# Why I cannot run a shell command using PHP 7?

Tags: php, python, exec

I'm having trouble running a python script using `shell_exec` or `exec` using PHP 7 (`PHP Version   7.0.33-0+deb9u3`).

If I run: `var_dump(shell_exec("/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/GTranslate/translator.py"));` or `var_dump(shell_exec("/home/pi/Documents/GTranslate/translator.py"));`,
I obtain back `NULL`.

### No problems with user permissions

I've checked the permission running:

```php
$scriptPath = "/home/pi/Documents/GTranslate/translator.py";
var_dump(array(
    'file' => is_file($scriptPath),
    'readable' => is_readable($scriptPath),
    'executable' => is_executable($scriptPath)
));
```

I've obtained everything true.

### Missing `safe_mode` from php.ini

In my php.ini (the one shown by `phpinfo();`) there is no fields like `safe_mode`. Reading the PHP Wiki since [PHP 5.4.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode-exec-dir) the function has been removed.

### `shell_exec()` is working

The funcion shell_exec() is not disabled because if I run the command:

```php
echo shell_exec("ls -halt /home/pi/Documents/GTranslate/translator.py");
```

I obtain back:

```
-r-xr-x--x 1 pi pi 1.7K Aug 11 12:13 /home/pi/Documents/GTranslate/translator.py
```

**Where is the problem?**

Comment: `/usr/bin/python3` really exists and working?

Comment: can you share `translator.py` script

Comment: @Grabatui yes, /usr/bin/python3 exists and is working. 
If I execute the argument of shell_exec() in a shell it executes the code correctly

Comment: @RedBottle currently, for testing pourpose, it executes a simple print('Hello world')

Comment: just wanted to check if you have `#!/usr/bin/env python` in your script

Comment: @RedBottle I see, btw yes, the script start correctly with the following shabang: `#!/usr/bin/env python3` If I run from the shell the script is executed correctly